# CakePHP i18n/i10n Routing

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

**Update:**

I'm using a shared CakePHP lib across several apps (with all of them living in subdomains).  They're not all nested the same; so, for example, on the filesystem I might have:

```
/foo
  .htaccess
  /1.0 (app)
  /1.1 (app)
  /1.2 (app)
  ...
/bar
  .htaccess
  /1.0 (app)
  /1.1 (app)
  /1.2 (app)
  ...
```

Where the .htaccess in each just defines which app is the default that requests are routed to within that subfolder, while all of them are still available by a direct url (eg `/foo/1.0/...`).

It seems that if I'm using the direct URL (eg not the .htaccess-rewritten one) it recognizes the routes appropriately, but if the URL is rewritten by .htaccess, it doesn't; it will invoke AppError::error404() with the ouput at the end of the question.  This doesn't seem right to me... if anyone has any insight, that would be awesome.

---

Hey guys,

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and having a routing issue.  The gist of the concept is this:

- I want to use 'en_us' style i18n/i10n, not simply 'en'
- I'm not using built-in i18n because of requirements to have some languages display pages with localized views (`views/:i18n/...`) and others to common views with calls to `__()`

So, I have routes set up like so:

```
$sI18nFormat = '/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}/';
Router::connect('/:i18n/:controller/:action',
    array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action', 'i18n' => ':i18n'),
    array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
Router::connect('/:i18n/:controller',
    array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => 'index', 'i18n' => ':i18n'),
    array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action',
    array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action', 'i18n' => 'en_us'),
    array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
Router::connect('/:controller',
    array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => 'index', 'i18n' => 'en_us'),
    array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
```

where obviously the routes are mirrored except that one has a dynamic `i18n` parameter passed, and the other has a static one.

The problem comes with using certain values for `:i18n` - for example, `en_us` is okay, but `fr_fr` seems to have Cake looking for `FrController` (not `FrFrController`) - seemingly because it's trying to work some magic with a built-in i18n `fr` prefix.

As an example, here's what `AppError::error404` is given:

```
Array
(
    [className] => FrController
    [webroot] => /path/to/webroot
    [url] => _fr
    [base] => /path/to/webroot
)
```

Is it possible to a) make Cake stop this so my routes work as expected, or b) tell Cake what format I want my i18n/i10n in so it doesn't try to do it its own way?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, it's "i18n" (eye-18-en) and *"l10n" (ell-10-en)*. :)

Comment: haha, too true... long day. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not (need to) delimit the Regex, and there should also be no need to populate the default parameter. Try this:

```
$sI18nFormat = '[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}';
Router::connect('/:i18n/:controller/:action', array(), array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
```

It's probably also failing because the URL does not match the full defined route. I.e., `/fr_fr/foo` will not match the above route, since it contains no `:action`. Try adding shorter variants as well:

```
Router::connect('/:i18n/:controller', array('action' => 'index'), array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
Router::connect('/:i18n', array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'index'), array('i18n' => $sI18nFormat));
```

Comment: It was definitely a bit too verbose... happily removed the unnecessary bits.  Question though - I thought that only the parameter itself was matched against the regex, not the entire URI?  If I have a defined route `/:i18n/:controller` that points to `:action => index`, why would that not match `/fr_fr/foo` (for example)?

Comment: Scratch that - after I resolved an .htaccess issue everything is working as expected.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at p28n? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/p0windah/2007/09/12/p28n-the-top-to-bottom-persistent-internationalization-tutorial

I found that it made the whole thing much less of a handful.

Comment: I did look into that before and I was a bit turned off by the need for an (effectively) redirect controller to switch languages.  I want language to be controlled by the URI, not by the session... and it seems that p28n ~= stock i18n in that regard... unless I'm missing something crucial.  Clue me in if I am!